# Poster layout generator?

Tags: data-visualization, visual-design

**Update**: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3eRv-4znU32QUZxa3hCSDJrSm8/view?usp=sharing) is an example (on the first slide) of a poster I'd like generated automatically when just given the components and told what order they should be in

Working in academia I often have to make posters for conferences and hours upon hours are spent merely moving text boxes around to create the layout of the poster in powerpoint

If I, for instance, have all my content across various slides on a powerpoint, is there software out there that will automatically create one poster-like powerpoint slide of all the content in an acceptable layout, keeping the chronological order?

Or any software that takes all the individual components of a poster and ,after given what order they should appear and which images correspond to which text, creates a poster with an acceptable layout using those components?

Comment: For which operating system do you need this? Is any type of software (e.g., including command line, and self-hosted/hosted Web apps) okay, or does it have to be desktop tool with GUI? -- Not sure how useful it would be, but could you share an example poster showing the layout you want to have?

Comment: See my update. I ended up giving up and dragging and dropping things around to get it done. But for the future it would be lovely to have this automated.

Comment: did you try out prezi ?

Comment: I've certainly seen that before and it looks powerful, but I'm looking for software that will design an research-grade poster that will be printed, not displayed via an electronic device. Sadly the conferences I attend don't have the most tech-savvy organizers.

Comment: @StefanSzekeres: What's prezi?

Comment: @DirkHaupt: Just wanted to say that that layout is not so great, i.e. there are too many 'imaginary lines' cutting up the poster horizontally and vertically which have a confusing effect; there's some overlap; very few things align; you (or perhaps other readers) might benefit from going through [this](http://hsp.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/ScientificPosters.pdf) presentation about poster design.

Comment: @einpoklum agree completely. I had limited time, hence my search for an automated solution. Imagine a piece of software developed by experts in data visualization so it has been coded with all the things in the presentation you linked. you input the images and text and parameters on which images are most important and it outputs a professionally laid out academic poster. I'd pay money for that. And as a student my net income is negative. I don't care. I'd still pay if it works well. I HATE putting posters together when there's other research to be done.